# Data-binding not working with dynamic component loader in angular2-universal-starter

Tags: object, dependency-injection, typescript, angular

I am using **angular2-universal-starter** project.

So i was trying to pass an object to a child component using @Input , but its not working correctly.

I have used dynamic component loader to load child component and I want to pass the object to child component.

Following is my code snippet:

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Directive, Renderer, DynamicComponentLoader, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';    
import {headingComponent} from './heading.component';
@Directive({
  selector: '[x-large]'
})
export class XLarge {
  constructor(element: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
    // we must interact with the dom through Renderer for webworker/server to see the changes
    renderer.setElementStyle(element.nativeElement, 'fontSize', 'x-large');
  }
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  directives: [    
    XLarge
  ],  
  template: `
    <div>
        <div>
        <span x-large>Hello, {{ user.name }}!</span>
        </div>
        <icici-heading [user]="user"></icici-heading>      
    </div>
`
})
export class App {
  public user;       
  constructor(dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, elementRef: ElementRef) {          
      dcl.loadNextToLocation(headingComponent, elementRef);
  }
  ngOnInit(){
      this.user = { "id": 11, "name": "Mr. Nice" };
  }  
}
```

**heading.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit,Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'icici-heading',
    template: `
        <div>
        <!--{{user.name}}-->this is not working
        {{name}}
       </div>
`   
 })

export class headingComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() user;
    name: string;
    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit() { 
        this.name="heading is rendered";
    }    
}
```

Comment: The title is misleading. Dependency injection is about what is passed for constructor parameters. Your question is about databinding.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer sugget suitable title for this please

Comment: Do you get an error message in the browser console?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer no.its because I am using this for server side rendering so no msgs are displayed in console.

Comment: I also don't understand why you add `<icici-heading [user]="user">` to your template **and** add it using `DynamicComponentLoader`. What exactly do you expect to happen? Data-binding to inputs of components added by DCL is not supported.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, can you provide a link to documentation that verifies data-binding to inputs of components loaded by DCL is not supported? I'm worried this is why my examples aren't working as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you just need to make your code more forgiving when the value is not yet available.

This will work:

```
{{user?.name}}
```

The Elvis or safe-navigation operator only evaluates `.name` when `user != null`

For dynamically added components you also need to pass values imperatively

```
dcl.loadNextToLocation(headingComponent, elementRef)
.then(cmpRef => cmpRef.instance.user = this.user);
```